# mysql TEMPORARY TABLE stored in ram?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I've developed a small c# application that uses quite intensive Database calculations.
I am hosting my application in a shared hosting environment. 
I am getting :

`mysql out of memory exception`

I am using quite a lot of **temporary tables.** Where are these tables stored?
Could this be the reason for this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Temporary tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) are stored in memory, but if the temporary table gets too large it will get moved to the file system. Lots of temporary tables can definitely eat up a lot of memory and cause other kinds of performance problems as well. Also, large result sets can cause similar issues, so it's a good idea to check you're only fetching what you need and that the keys and indexes are correctly defined.